# Using Newton's Method, solve the following equation,

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Using Newton's Method, solve the following equation:

$\displaystyle 0 = \frac{1}{ 2}+ \frac{1}{4}x^2- x\sin(x)- \frac{1}{2}\cos(2x) $
iterate until you achieve an accuracy of $\displaystyle 10^{−5}$ with:

$ \displaystyle p_0 = \frac{\pi}{3}
\\
p_0 = 3\pi$

How do I do the calculations to get the precision $\displaystyle 10^{−5}$?

What I can understand from the exercise is that I must apply the method twice taking $\frac{\pi}{3}$ as the initial value first.
And recalculate using $3\pi$. The detail is that I can't get it into my head when I should stop, how I can know that I have reached the requested accuracy?

Comment: For an accuracy of $10^{-5}$, you need to stop as soon as the next iteration differs from the previous one from the 6th decimal place onwards.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: When evaluating the derivative at $\frac{\pi}{3}$ it gives zero, therefore I cannot apply Newton's method at this point. I am right?

Comment: I have yet to write an answer detailing an example as you asked for, but it is coming. In the meantime, the derivative is certainly defined at $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, so I suspect a mistake on your part. What expression do you have for the derivative?

Comment: $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}x^2-xsin(x)-\frac{1}{2}cos(2x)$

Comment: when deriving $\frac{x}{2}+sin(2x)-xcos(x)-sin(x)$ when evaluating $\frac{\pi}{3} $in the derived expression it gives me $0.00425$

Comment: Okay, yes, that's the correct derivative. But $0.00425\neq 0$, so there's no problem with Newton's method

Comment: I need your help to solve this exercise, I am very confused, can you detail it?

Comment: Just to be clear: your confusion is about what it means to calculate to an accuracy of $10^{-5}$, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151982/discussion-between-angelabayona-and-h-sapiens-rex).

Comment: @Homo sapiens rex, Yes please